# Angular get JSON data with ajax

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax

How can I get json data via ajax with angular? I tried a lot but my code is not working. 
My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="test">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('test', [])
      .controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data = [];
        $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function(res) {
          $scope.data = JSON.parse(res);
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{item.id}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: would you please explain what happens with your code? Does it throw an error in the browser console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this..

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('test', [])
        app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function(res,status,xhr) {
                $scope.data = res.data;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: @Enes Giray glad to help you.Best of luck ahead.